I'm a Hindu man and I'm willing to marry an Muslim woman will allah accept this and forgive her and why Allah is against woman interfaith marriage?
I'm a Hindu man and i'm in relationship with a Muslim girl and allah says interfaith marriage is accepted only for Muslim men and not woman and there are some reasons for them. And my major question is if she seeks solution for this they say the man should be converted to Muslim and then only it can be accepted or else she have to leave the relationship and there is nothing if the Muslim girl hurt the feelings of man. And Allah have anything for hurting the feeling is of a man. And why they are not allowing woman for interfaith marriage.

Also see Reasons for not allowing interfaith marriage

Welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that in Islam a women can't marry but a Muslim husband.

In Islam, the rules regarding marriage between Muslims and non-Muslims are guided by the Qur'an and the Hadith (sayings of the Prophet Muhammad, peace be upon him). The general rule is that a Muslim man is allowed to marry a woman from the People of the Book (i.e., a Jewish or Christian woman) and HIndu are not included so even a man cant marry a hindu girl, However Islam encourages men to marry within the Muslim community for the sake of religious unity, and it is highly recommended that Muslims marry other Muslims to avoid potential spiritual challenges., but a Muslim woman is not allowed to marry a non-Muslim man, whether from the People of the Book or otherwise.
Quran (2:221):
“And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe. And indeed, a believing slave woman is better than a polytheistic woman, even though she might please you. And do not marry polytheistic men until they believe. And indeed, a believing slave is better than a polytheistic man, even though he might please you.”
https://quran.com/en/al-baqarah/221
This verse establishes that Muslim women cannot marry non-Muslim men, but it allows Muslim men to marry women from the People of the Book, as long as the marriage is in harmony with the Islamic faith.
Quran (5:5):
“This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those who were given the Scripture is lawful for you, and your food is lawful for them.”
https://quran.com/en/al-maidah/5
This verse permits Muslim men to marry women from the People of the Book (Jews and Christians), but it does not extend this allowance to Muslim women marrying non-Muslim men.
even man cant marry a hindu girl because she is not from the people of  the book
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/8015/can-a-muslim-marry-a-hindu
Regarding feelings, Islam emphasizes kindness, but the priority is the spiritual well-being of both individuals, and sometimes difficult decisions are made for that reason. Hurting someone’s feelings is discouraged, but preserving faith takes precedence in these matters.
watch this video is a similar question you asked a scholar responed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foYbrOn3fT0
May Allah guide both of you to what is best

Try to add references with claims!

assalam alaikom,i dont understand what you mean,the answe isnt correct?

Your answers could be heavily improved and clarified if you used the formatting tools provided and added links to trusted sites from where you picked up the references from such as quranic verses or hadiths .

You say This verse establishes that Muslim women cannot marry non-Muslim men, but it allows Muslim men to marry women from the People of the Book, as long as the marriage is in harmony with the Islamic faith. But is this interpretation of that verse really correct? That verse tells us both men and women can't marry those people until they believe.

All tge scholars agree with this there not disagreement on this matter
